# How to set a limit on a command per guild?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

how to set a limit on a command per guild? for example: you can use /snoop in MYSERVER for every 2 hours.

its like how disboard's /bump command works.

Comment: I don't think this question is appropriate for stackoverflow. Unless you're using some kind of API to interact with discord.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried and where you're getting stuck? For a few pointers, you'll probably need to create an object that stores guild ids and timestamps; every time a user runs a command, you can check the object to see if the current timestamp is greater than the timestamp stored in the object, then update the object with a new timestamp. Just some tips to get you headed in the right direction.

Comment: Hello! You’ve probably been downvoted because you haven’t included any code or any attempt to solve your issue. Please include your attempt at solving the issue and any relevant existing code. @marco-a I believe this question (if edited to include code) *is* appropriate for Stack Overflow as it is about implementing a Discord bot command in Discord.js.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the userId along with the timestamp of the time they are allowed to use this command again and every time the user tries to invoke the command just check that the current timestamp is either greater than or equal to said timestamp stored.

To create the timestamp just add the necessary amount of time needed to wait to the current timestamp at the time that a user invokes the command.